# ajax response isn't pre-processing as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, safe-browsing

I'm trying to parse the response data from querying google's safe browsing api and the response seems to be a javascript prototype object, in which i'm having no luck trying to convert or parse to JSON. My ajax call is the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );

//first fake links and event listeners
AddFakeLinks(faulty_links, curr_list);

//url checker action
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 

    var api_url = "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?"
    var key = 'AIz________________________ns'
    api_url += "key="
    api_url += key

    var payload = 
    {
        "client":{
            "clientId": "_________________.googleusercontent.com",
            "clientVersion": "1.0.0",
        },
        "threatInfo": {
            "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
            "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
            "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
            "threatEntries": [
              {"url": "http://www.pitt.edu/"},
              {"url": "http://www.exchange.pitt.edu/"}
            ]
          }
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: api_url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        xhr: function(){
            //upload Progress
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    var percent = 0;
                    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                    var total = event.total;
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    }
                    //update progressbar
                    $("#upload-progress .progress-bar").css("width", + percent +"%");
                }, true);
            }
            return xhr;
        },
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.error(textStatus, errorThrown) 
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#server-results").html(response);
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The console has the following output:
[image]

The network console is shown with response of 200 ok:

[image]

Comment: How can you tell the difference between your success and error handlers? Try `error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.error(textStatus, errorThrown) }` instead

Comment: What does your _Network_ console show? Is the request successful?

Comment: @Phil 200 ok, I uploaded a screenshot of it.

Comment: Did you see my first comment about your `$.ajax` error handler?

Comment: @Phil I added it as you can see in my code above, no error is thrown when executed.

Comment: I think you need to look a little closer. You still have your original error handler near the bottom of your script which will override the one you have near the top

Comment: @Phil  Okay, I altered the code and deleted the my original error handler. Console isn't showing anything different.

Comment: Please show us the response payload of the request.

Comment: @EternalHour How could I go about doing that? There is nothing in the response tab of the network console, just an empty set of curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this API at all. But after looking at the documentation, the issue appears to be that there is no match for your request.

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api

> Response body
>
> The response body includes the match information (the list names and
>   the URLs found on those lists, the metadata, if available, and the
>   cache durations). For more details, see the threatMatches.find
>   response body and the explanations that follow the code example.
>
> **Note: If there are no matches (that is, if none of the URLs specified
>   in the request are found on any of the lists specified in a request),
>   the HTTP POST response simply returns an empty object in the response
>   body.**